# Как ускорить рисование графиков в Java?

Tags: java, javafx, график

Как ускорить рисование графика в Java? Мне нужно это для эффективного вывода графиков с большими датасетами (100-200 тысяч точек). Думаю распараллелить код, который отрисовывает график, но не понимаю как. Любые предложения...

Вот вполне очевидный код, но где и как его ускорять непонятно:

```java
public class FXLineChart {
    private List<Long> dataset;

    public FXLineChart(List<Long> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    public void drawChart(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Chart");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Check dataset");

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.size(); i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, dataset.get(i)));
        }

        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите порекомендовать библиотеку JFreeChart, то там такая же проблема - непонятно как параллелить код. И вообще я хотел написать свою библиотеку по отрисовке графиков с большими датасетами, но пока не понимаю, на основе чего она будет - javafx, jfreechart или ещё что-то.

P.S. Приведённый выше код (то есть построение графика средствами JavaFX) тормозит на нескольких тысячах точек, JFreeChart получше в этом плане, но с нескольких десятков тысяч точек тоже начинается тормоз...

Comment: А поработать над сжатием данных не пробовали? Зачем вам 200к точек все равно будет каша и не понять все

Comment: Рекомендую убавить количество данных да так чтоб картинка в целом не сильно отличалась.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, я приделаю масштабирование и каши не будет

Comment: Если делать масштабирование то зачем всё показывать. Показывайте всегда часть

Comment: Просто не вижу смысла помечать все 200к точек. Сокращяйте до разумных пределов и все будет норм

Comment: Рисуйте график всегда что на нём было не более 1к точек. Думаю от этого страдать никто не будет. Как говориться геометрия точная наука над неточными чертежам

Comment: @AzizUmarov, то есть при перемещении по графику и его масштабировании тоже не более 1к точек оставлять? Такого можно добиться, используя javafx или jfreechart?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, вопрос, возможно, покажется немного не по теме, но не подскажете, что значит строить графики в реал тайме? Не очень понимаю, как это в моём случае будет выглядеть...

Comment: Реал тайме это данные приходят постоянном отрисовывать надо постоянно. Вы заменяете пульс и тут же показываете на графике значение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124366/discussion-between-alex-and-aziz-umarov).

Comment: Я думаю, если вам действительно надо быстро отрисовывать большое количество данных, то стандартные средства рисования диаграмм из `JavaFX` не подойдут -- там внутри слишком много всякой объектности, это будут тормоза, перерасход памяти, лишняя нагрузка на сборщик мусора. Не рассчитаны они на большие графики. Насчет JFreeChart не знаю, не пробовал, но тоже сомнительно. Возможно, лучшее решение -- это реализовать собственную отрисовку, то есть рисовать руками на `Canvas`, используя напр `Path` с его `lineTo()` и т.п.  Но это довольно много работы.

Comment: @m.vokhm, есть ли более простые решения? И получится ли потом преобразовать такие графики в svg, чтобы вставлять на html страницу?

Comment: @Alex насчет более простых решений не знаю, я в своё время не нашёл. Я делал подобное на `SWT` (не графики, но тоже много рисования и нужно быстро). Успешно, но довольно муторно. Насчет `Canvas` и `SVG`, как я понимаю, да, но я не пробовал, только читал об этом. Самая толкова книжка по `JavaFX` из того, что я видел, это Kishori Sharan, "Learn JavaFX 8"